# How to prevent friends adding me to their Facebook groups without my consent

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

A friend of mine on Facebook has added me to her Facebook group without my consent. I had to visit the group page and click on "Leave group" to leave it.

I don't want my friends to add me to their groups without my consent? Where is the related setting in the options list?

Answer (score 8):

You can't prevent people from adding you to groups - you can only leave a group once added.

[See this Facebook article](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=18897)

> **Can I prevent people from adding me to a new group?**
>
> The functionality of approving a group
>   membership is not available. Similar
>   to being tagged in a photo, you can
>   only be added to a group by one of
>   your friends. When a friend adds you
>   to a group, a story in the group (and
>   in News Feed for Open or Closed
>   groups) will indicate that your friend
>   has added you to a group.
>
> Please keep in mind:
>
> - Only your friends can add you to groups.
> - When a friend adds you to a group, you'll get a notification right away.
> - You can leave a group anytime. To do so, just go to the group page and
>     click "Leave Group" in the right-hand
>     column. Once you leave a group, you
>     can't be added by anyone else unless
>     you explicitly request to be re-added

Comment: I don't agree with the answer. Actually, I created a group yesterday and I added few of my friends and 2 were not added. They somehow did it. Thanks